# Using matplotlib to plot a matrix with the third variable as source for a color map

Tags: matplotlib, matrix

Say you have the matrix given by three arrays, being:

x = N-dimensional array.

y = M-dimensional array.

And z is a set of "somewhat random" values from -0.3 to 0.3 in a NxM shape. I need to create a plot in which the x values are in the x-axis, y values are in the y-axis and using z as the source to indicate the intensity of each pixel with a color map.

So far, I have tried using

```
plt.contourf(x,y,z)
```

and the resulting plot is very nice for me (attached at the end of this paragraph), but a smoothing is automatically applied to the plot! I need to be able to distinguish the pixels and I cannot find a way to do it.
[contourf result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMbHM.png)

I have also studied the possibility of using

```
ax.matshow(z)
```

in order to sucesfully see the pixels... but then I am struggling trying to personalize the x and y axis, since only the index of the pixel is shown (see below).
[matshow result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vKor.png)

Would you please give me some ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Try [matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html).  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: That absolutely did it! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: np.  Please upvote my comment if it was helpful.

Comment: @Bill Rather provide your comment as answer (and add why that would solve the problem). In this way it is preserved and can be upvoted.

Comment: I'm trying to, but as I just created my account I am not able to. However, as soon as I can I will come back to it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Without more information on your x,y data it's hard to know, but I would guess you are looking for [`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html).

```
plt.pcolormesh(x,y,z)
```

This would take the x and y data as input and hence shows the z data at the appropriate coordinates.

Comment: This comparison seems useful, too: https://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_demo.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `imshow` with the keyword `interpolation='nearest'`.

```
plt.imshow(z, interpolation='nearest')
```